# How a real kernel switches context

Tags: kernel

I know of several ways to interrupt threads of execution and swap contexts to another thread of execution by now. But when the kernel receives an interrupt from the hardware and the current code is stopped from executing. How does the kernel switch contexts to another thread. Does it also call simple C routines to do this? Or does it have to execute custom assembly code to achieve this?

Consider this kernel to be running on a uniprocessor system. I have only ever dealt with OS concepts in User space so I am not very clear on how kernel code works from a lower level.

Note: If you would like to explain this within the context of an existing kernel (maybe Linux) go ahead! I know I worded this question a bit ambiguously.

Thank you!

Comment: they way each kernel handles is specific to the kernel. Besides you are writing a kernel , which means there is no simple library call, you have to handle saving of registers, stack pointers , TLB flushing and many more. Its  not going to simple and also dependent on architecture too

Comment: Lets simplify this to be extremely similar to how Linux does this. I will update my question

Comment: What does it have to do with C++?

Comment: @curiousguy I was thinking in C++ when I asked this

Comment: I am sure there are loads of resources online, google them and you can find out

Comment: i am flagging it to be closed, too generic and google can fetch the answer

Comment: @Pradheep some resources that I find related to these things are often wrong I have found. I trust the stackoverflow C++ question answering community to know their concepts!

Comment: stack overflow community expects you to digest and expects you to ask specific question

Comment: I would start here: https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/index.html

Comment: Could the linux kernel simply call swapcontext?

Answer (score 0):

If an interrupt doesn't trigger a pending context switch, it just returns. If an interrupt does trigger a pending context switch, it exits via a "dispatcher" which does the context switch. The "dispatcher" also does context switches based on time slices or when a pending higher priority thread becomes runnable, usually due to some operating system synchronization event being signaled.

If nested interrupts are allowed, only the initial interrupt may exit via the dispatcher. The initial interrupt sets some type of indicator so that any nested interrupts know they are not the initial interrupt and don't attempt to exit via the dispatcher.

Comment: but how exactly does the dispatcher switch contexts? Is it implemented in assembly?

Comment: @Curious: If you want to know "how exactly" it works, then you should clone the Linux kernel repository and look at the code directly yourself.

Comment: @ray Could you direct me to which folder I should look at?

Comment: Could the linux kernel simply call swapcontext ?

Comment: @Curious - I don't know about the internals of Linux or Windows, just some  simple embedded operating systems.

Comment: @Curious: Perhaps finding a function called `schedule()` and following from there *might* be a good starting point. The scheduler and the timer interrupt code *might* help you get to that location. It's simply a large and complicated codebase. It might be easier for you to get an introductory book :)